# swig ignore std::enable_shared_from_this

Tags: python, c++11, templates, swig

I am trying to ignore std::enable_shared_from_this base class.

Below are my files

test.h:

```
#ifndef _TEST_H_INCLUDED_
#define _TEST_H_INCLUDED_

#include <memory>

class Test : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Test> {
public:
    Test() : val_(0) {}
    virtual ~Test() {}

    int GetVal() const;
    void SetVal(int val);

private:
    int val_;
};

#endif // _TEST_H_INCLUDED_
```

test.cpp:

```
#include "test.h"

int Test::GetVal() const { return val_; }
void Test::SetVal(int val) { val_ = val; }
```

test_module.i:

```
%module test_module

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%include <memory>

%ignore std::enable_shared_from_this<Test>;
%template(TestFromThis) std::enable_shared_from_this<Test>;
typedef std::enable_shared_from_this<Test> TestFromThis;

%include "test.h"
```

test.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import test_module

if __name__ == "__main__":
    test = test_module.Test()
    res = test.GetVal()
    print("res={}".format(res))
    sys.exit()
```

Makefile:

```
SWIG = /volume/evo/files/opt/poky/3.0.2-35/sysroots/x86_64-pokysdk-linux/usr/bin/swig4
CCX = g++
LD = g++

all: test_module.py

test_module.py: test.h test.cpp test_module.i
        ${SWIG} -python -py3 -c++ -cppext cpp -I/usr/include/c++/9 test_module.i
        ${CCX} -std=c++11 -O2 -fPIC -c test.cpp
        ${CCX} -std=c++11 -O2 -fPIC -c test_module_wrap.cpp -I/usr/include/python3.8
        ${LD} -shared test.o test_module_wrap.o -o _test_module.so

run: test_module.py
        python3 ./test.py

clean:
        rm -rf *~ test_module.py *_wrap.* *.o *.so __pycache__
```

When I compile I got the following errors:

test_module.i:10: Error: Template 'enable_shared_from_this' undefined.

test.h:6: Warning 401: Nothing known about base class 'std::enable_shared_from_this< Test >'. Ignored.

test.h:6: Warning 401: Maybe you forgot to instantiate 'std::enable_shared_from_this< Test >' using %template.

If I remove every occurrence std::enable_shared_from_this it will work without problem.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved it by adding a dummy std::enable_shated_from_this class and ignoring it.

test_module.i:

```
%module test_module

%{
#include "test.h"
%}

%ignore std::enable_shared_from_this<Test>;
class std::enable_shared_from_this<Test> {};

%include "test.h"
```